# Matrix kind-of program

Tags: python

I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` on the following code, why?

```
def temp_media(c, l):
    c_ini = c
    l_ini = l
    res_vert = 0
    res_horiz = 0
    dim = dimensoes()
    c_max = dim[0] // 2
    l_max = dim[1]
    for l in l_max:
        for c in c_max:
            res_vert = res_vert + calcula_temp(c, l)
        res_horiz = res_horiz + calcula_temp(c, l)
    return (((res_horiz / (c_max - c_ini)) + (res_vert / (l_max - l_ini))) / 2)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: L_max is an integer ... and cant be iterated ... c_max is also just an integer ...

Comment: what does `dimensoes()` return here?

Comment: I know this is not the answer you are expecting but, I strongly recommend you don't use l as a variable name, never.

Comment: dimensoes() returns this:

(2300, 1400)

Comment: l_max in this case is 1400 and c_max is 2300, how can i solve this error ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `range` (or `xrange` in python 2) in your for loops:

```
c_max = dim[0] // 2
l_max = dim[1]
for l in range(l_max):
    for c in range(c_max):
```

Comment: i am using python 3.2.3, and the range solution doesnt work :/

Comment: @user1798666: define "doesn't work" - does it give an error message?

Comment: it gives an error mesage, xrange doesnt exist or something close